# UserNotificationListener throws an exception when requesting permissions

Tags: c#, uwp

I'm attempting to write a console application to intercept desktop notifications. This function throws an exception when I try to request said permissions.

I'm following these docs:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/apps/design/shell/tiles-and-notifications/notification-listener

Code:

```
        static async Task<bool> IsNotificationPermissionsGranted() {
            try {
                UserNotificationListener listener = UserNotificationListener.Current;
                UserNotificationListenerAccessStatus accessStatus = await listener.RequestAccessAsync();
                Console.WriteLine(accessStatus);
                switch (accessStatus) {
                    case UserNotificationListenerAccessStatus.Allowed:
                        return true;
                    case UserNotificationListenerAccessStatus.Denied:
                        return false;
                    case UserNotificationListenerAccessStatus.Unspecified:
                        return false;
                }
                return false;
            } catch (Exception error) {
                Console.WriteLine(error);
                return false;
            }
        }
```

Error:

```
System.Exception: Element not found. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80070490)
   at VRCOCSN.Program.IsNotificationPermissionsGranted()
```

I have already enabled the capability in the manfiest.

Comment: It sounds suspiciously like you haven't checked that the listener exists on your device.  There's a part of the tutorial that mentions you should check if it exists first.  `if (ApiInformation.IsTypePresent("Windows.UI.Notifications.Management.UserNotificationListener"))`  If the listener does not exist, I would expect an error similar to the one you're seeing.  The solution, if indeed this is the problem, is to update your Windows.

Comment: @DanRayson Windows is up to date, and I do the API check before invoking this function.

Answer (score -4):

you can use this code:

```
$(function () {
    self.addEventListener('notificationclick', function (e) {
        var notification = e.notification;
        var action = e.action;
        if (action === 'close') {
            notification.close();
        }
    });
});

function requestPermission() {

    if (!("Notification" in window)) {
        alert("Sorry you didnt allow notify");
    }
    Notification.requestPermission(function (userChoice) {
        /*     console.log('result: ', userChoice);*/
        if (userChoice === 'denied') {
            alert('Notification Permission Denied !');

        } else {
            /*console.log('Notification Accept !');*/
            storePushSub();
            showSuccessMessage("You Allowed Thnks");
        }
    });
};

function showSuccessMessage(message) {
    var options = {
        body: 'Notify',
        icon: '/assets/images/icons/icon-96x96.png',
        image: '/assets/images/icons/M.png',
        badge: '/assets/images/icons/icon-96x96.png',
        dir: 'rtl',
        vibrate: [100, 50, 200],
    };
    navigator.serviceWorker.ready.then(function (registration) { console.log('okkkkk', registration); registration.showNotification(message, options); });
}
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: This question is for a C# console application, your answer is written in JavaScript for browser code.

Comment: please add more details, instead of just the code. That would be helpful to understand the context and answer in detail